# Get value of second <table>, and second <td> using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying get values from a shoutcast songhistory ([link](http://138.36.236.207:8000/played.html)).

The markup of page have 2 tables like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Header Link 1</td>
        <td>Header Link 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td>Lengh of song 1</td> </tr> 
        <tr> <td>Song Title 1</td> </tr> 
        <tr> <td>Lengh of song 2</td> </tr> 
        <tr> <td>Song Title 2</td> </tr> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I only need get the **song title** and save this on a database.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="titulos";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "No se puede conectar a la base de datos");

$html = file_get_html('http://138.36.236.207:8000/played.html');
$guardardato = "";

// Buscar 
foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr', 2) as $datossc) {
    foreach($datossc->find('td') as $titulo) {

        echo $titulo->plaintext .'<br>';
        $guardardato .= $titulo->plaintext;
    }
}

$guardardato = mysql_real_escape_string($guardardato);
$query = "INSERT INTO data(name) VALUES('$guardardato')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$html->clear();
unset($html);
?>
```

The sql process is ok, but the simple dom does work..

I get that error:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\radioargenta\oyentes\indexprueba.php** on line 19

[image]

Can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what's the output you get?

Comment: blank data. No find any :(

Comment: I edited my question with more information

Comment: Is that your real code: `find('table', 2)->->find('tr', 2)`?

Comment: Is it a `copy mistake`: `foreach($html->find('table', 2)->->find('tr', 2) as $datossc) {`? as it should be `foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr', 2)` if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, bad edit. I correct this and i've same error.

Comment: Can you please try to check if `$html` is really being set correctly? What's `var_dump($html);` prints?

Comment: With: `foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr', 2)` i get: ** Call to a member function find()** on a non-object on line **20**. Line 20: `foreach($datossc->find('td') as $titulo) {`

Comment: `$html` is correctly set. If i use this: http://pastebin.com/dnngMCDH
i get: http://prntscr.com/6vk2es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `for` loop as follows:

```
foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr') as $datossc) {
    echo $datossc->find('td', 1)->plaintext .'<br>';
    $guardardato .= $datossc->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
}
```

Note that you will have `Song Title` in the output as well.

Also, are you sure that you want to append all titles in `$guardardato`? This will just concatenate the titles, e.g. `Song TitleAle Ceberio - LaCuartetera.NetAlcides - Tan bonita pero muy celosaAgrupaciOn Marylin - Agru...`. Perhaps what you want to do is:

```
$guardardato = array();

foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr') as $datossc) {
    $title = $datossc->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    if ($title != 'Song Title') {  
        echo $title .'<br>';
        $guardardato[] = $title;
    }
}

foreach($guardardato as $i) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($i);
    $query = "INSERT INTO data(name) VALUES('" . $value . "')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thats work, with some fix i get what i want. Thanks so much :)